# IOS Push Notification not working in Producation: fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using apple push notification to send notifications to a user when an other user send him a message.
The code i am using is working fine in development mode but when i uploaded my app to app store my users don't get notifications.

So I have created a new pem file (BUT WITH PRODUCATION certification) according to this tutorial(same tutorial i have used for producation):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

**In apple member center the notification is enable for the Distribution mode

But now there is a problem, when the server try to send the notification:

**fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe'**

**My Code:**

```
 $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'file.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

        // Open a connection to the APNS server
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
                     'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                     $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

        if (!$fp)
            return;

    $message = "Hello world";
    $deviceToken = "token...";

    // Create the payload body
        $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,
                             'sound' => 'default');

        // Encode the payload as JSON
        $payload = json_encode($body);

        // Build the binary notification
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

        // Close the connection to the server
        fclose($fp);
```

I don't know what to do, I have searched all the web for a solution with no good results.
Hope you will help me, Thanks =)

Comment: This error also occurs when the production gateway is addressed with the developer certificate  (or vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the notification to the sandbox server - `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`

You should send it to the production server `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

Comment: This help me for fixing the broken pipe, thanks =) BUT the notifications still not working, now the server look like its working fine, there is no any messagse or exceptions but the users still dont get the notification. What else can i do?

Comment: @user3783623 Make sure you are using a production device token (and not a sandbox token)

Comment: I checked it with other devices that are not production device token and still don't work. What am I missing?

Comment: @user3783623 If you send sandbox device token to the production APNS server using the production push certificate, then of course it wouldn't work. You must use production device tokens to send push notifications to the production push env.

Comment: But my server send the notification it doesn't know the user device token that send the notification.

Comment: @user3783623 If it's your production server, it should only contain production device tokens, otherwise you'll get into trouble when you try to send to sandbox tokens.

Comment: My producation sever sends notification only to producation device token but still the my users don't get the notifications. Please try to help me.

Comment: @user3783623 Try to send to a single device token which you are sure is a production token (for example, un-install and install the app on your device and try to send a push notification to the device token you'll get. Make sure you are installing a production build). If that doesn't work, read [this troubleshooting doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I m getting the same issue on production and resolve the issue using below steps. 
you need to change in one line, and need to closed the connection adding one additional line. I have describable below line line line.

```
Step 1: Change below 
From 
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', 
$err, 
$errstr, 
60, 
STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, 
$ctx);

To below:   
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', 
$err, 
$errstr, 
60, 
STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, 
$ctx);


Step 2: add below line just before the "$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));"

stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);
```